Code listing over multiple pages with the minted package causes underfull warning
I am using the minted package to include code snippets in my documents. I have a long Python code, which I include using \inputminted{python}{demo.py}. The code spans multiple pages, so it gives me an "Underfull \vbox" warning. How can I fix this and correctly include code snippets that span multiple pages in my document?
Here's a MWE:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[marginparwidth=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[table, x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{minted}

\geometry{left=1cm, right=1cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm}

% Minted settings
\usemintedstyle{manni}

\definecolor{code-bg}{gray}{0.9}
\setminted[python]{
    linenos,
    tabsize=4,
    frame=lines,
    framesep=2mm,
    bgcolor=code-bg,
    fontsize=\footnotesize
}

\begin{document}
\inputminted{python}{demo.py}
\end{document}

Just make sure demo.py is long enough to span multiple pages (For me it took 70 lines of code), and you will get the Underfull warning.

It's really unlikely to get such warnings with the article class. Anyway, the warning is not an error.

This code with a long enough demo.py gives me the warning both on my local machine and on Overleaf.
